# Why Git diff of 2 versions of a single file is empty?

Tags: git, git-diff

I'm trying to find the git diff between 2 versions of a file. **I do not want to use the SHA.**

I have tried a dozen variations, the diff comes up empty. I am not looking for a diff against the working or staged files. I edited the path on the output so the line would fit without wrapping.

I am using posh-git powershell.

Here is proof the file exists:

```
ls src/G01/P001_MultiplesOf3And5.java

Directory: U:\dev\workspace\ProjectEuler\src\G01


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name  
----                -------------     ------ ----  
-a---         5/24/2015   7:38 AM       1612 P001_MultiplesOf3And5.java
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
U: git diff HEAD~1..HEAD src/G01/P001_MultiplesOf3And5.java

U: git diff HEAD~1..HEAD -- src/G01/P001_MultiplesOf3And5.java

U:
```

I read that this should work: `git diff $start_commit..$end_commit -- path/to/file`

You can see the diff comes up empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did the file change in the last commit? If the diff is empty, the file probably hasn't changed.

Comment: You were right.  I figured out the solution from another comment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the last two commits that did include a given file.
Those might not be `HEAD` or `HEAD~`. If `yourFile` is unchanged in `HEAD` and `HEAD~`, then `git diff` returns nothing.

The full command would be:

```
 git diff $(git log -n2 --pretty=format:%H -- yourFile | awk '{print $1}' | tac) -- yourFile
```

With:

- `git log -n2 --pretty=format:%H -- yourFile`: will get the last 2 commits
- `awk '{print $1}'`: make sure they are printed one per line
- `tac`: reverse the order (oldest commit, then newest)
- `git diff $(...) -- yourFile`: does a diff of `yourFile` using relevant commit SHA1.

Comment: Thanks! I had the wrong understanding of commits versus versions.  After running your commands, I was able to get the difference between the last two versions of a file.

Answer (score 0):

> `git diff HEAD~1..HEAD`

`HEAD~1..HEAD` specifies a single commit: `HEAD`.  [Lose the dots](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).